# Cuando borro 1 objeto del almacén, se borra 1 en cantidad de todos los objetos que haya

Tags: javascript

Estoy creando un botón en el html dinámicamente, cada vez que añado un producto al almacén:

[image: función pintarCarrito]

Para borrar un producto del almacén, llamo a la función BorrarRegistro, pero cuando clico en un botón resta 1 en cantidad de todo lo que haya:

[image: función borrarRegistro]

Comment: las imagenes de código no suelen ser muy bien recibidas, copia y pega el código mejor, asi podemos nosotros también copiarlo y pegarlo.

Answer (score 0):

El problema viene porque la función `borrarRegistro` no sabe en que botón has pulsado y está recorriendo el almacén. Creo que tu confusión viene por la función `document.getElementById(almacen[item].tipo)` la cual te devuelve el elemento con ese id en ese documento y dado que estas recorriendo el almacen, serán todos sus elementos. Por el if que incluyes a continuación diría que lo que quieres es obtener el id del elemento que se ha pulsado para comparar con él. Te dejo un ejemplo de como se puede hacer eso [aquí](https://jsfiddle.net/4tpbqyva/1/)

Código Html + Javascript que obtiene el id del elemento pulsado:

```
<button id="un_id" onClick="alPulsar()">Boton</button>

function alPulsar()
{
    alert(event.srcElement.id);
}
```

Nota: Por favor, en el futuro trata de pegar el código con formato en lugar de imágenes para facilitar las respuestas.

Comment: Perfecto muchas gracias, me ha servido!!
Y tendré en cuenta lo del código para futuras dudas ^^
Saludos!

Comment: @NewbieDev Me alegro que te haya servido!, si puedes marca la pregunta como resuelta. Gracias y un saludo!